# How to scale control and layout it properly in javafx

Tags: java, css, layout, javafx, effects

I want position Rating control (http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#rating) as below:

```
<HBox spacing="10.0" alignment="CENTER" >
         <children>
            <Label text="Rating" />
            <Rating  fx:id="rating1" styleClass="scale-half" />
            <Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
            <Label text="Difficulty" />
            <Rating  fx:id="rating2" styleClass="scale-half" />
         </children>
</HBox>
```

and in css:

```
.scale-half {
    -fx-scale-x:0.5;
    -fx-scale-y:0.5;
}
```

Original size of Rating control is to big for my purpouse, so I want to scale it.

It is the problem, that after scalling, layout bounds of Rating's control is the same as without scalling.

I tried wrap this control by Group container.

That helped a little. Layout was ok, but after move mouse over the star in Rating control, shadow effect occurred and layout bounds increased.

Entire HBox increased too, so the end effect was very bad: jittering layout.

How to avoid that?

Answer (score -3):

You can try with zoom instead of scaling. But, since zoom will not work in FireFox or Opera, try all the following:

```
.scale-half {
    zoom: 0.5; /* IE */
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5); /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.5); /* Opera */
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); /* Safari And Chrome */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: scale(0.5); /* Standard Property */
    transform-origin: 0 0; 
}
```